# Beautiful Soup - XML Parsing - Attribute Error Exception (Handling Null Values)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

inputFile = open("test.xml","r")

data = BeautifulSoup(inputFile,'xml')
stop_points = data.find_all('Location')

l = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id','One','Two','Three','Four','Five'])
pos= 0
for stop in stop_points:
    l.append(stop.get('id'))
    l.append(stop.find('One').text)
    l.append(stop.find('Two').text)
    l.append(stop.find('Three').text)
    l.append(stop.find('Four').text)
    l.append(stop.find('Five').text)
    df.loc[pos] = l
    l = []
    pos+=1
print(df)

df.to_sql('Location',conn,if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

However, in some instances 'Location' doesn't have all of the elements ('One','Two','Three','Four', or 'Five'). When the script iterates to a location that doesn't have all of these elements an Attribute Error Exception is thrown:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Therefore, I believe I need to do a presence check before attempting to append the '.text' to the list. However, I don't really want to add five 'IF' statements as this isn't very elegant.

For reference, here is a sample of the XML file:

```
 <Location id="00000">
              <Translation>
                <One>111111</One>
                <Two>222222</Two>
                <Four>-5.0</Four>
                <Five>50.0</Five>
              </Translation>
            </Location>
 <Location id="11111">
              <Translation>
                <One>111111</One>
                <Two>222222</Two>
                <Three>-5.0</Three>
                <Five>50.0</Five>
              </Translation>
            </Location>
 <Location id="22222">
              <Translation>
                <One>111111</One>
                <Two>222222</Two>
              </Translation>
            </Location>
```

Comment: Iterate through the list of parameters and put a single `if` statement for presence. Else continue.

Comment: Can you post a representative sample of the xml in `inputFile`? Also, since you are dealing with xml, you may want to parse using using an xml parser like lxml and use xpath.

Comment: The sample XML doesn't contain any `<one>, <two>, <three>, <four> and <five>`. Is that intentional?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't spot my obvious mistake. I have now corrected the XML sample to better illustrate the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your html looks something like this:

```
locations = """
<locations>
<Location id="00000">
              <Translation>
                <Easting>111111</Easting>
                <Northing>222222</Northing>
                <Longitude>-5.0</Longitude>
                <Latitude>50.0</Latitude>
              </Translation>
            </Location>
<Location id="00001">
              <Translation>
                <Easting>4444</Easting>
                <Northing>5555</Northing>
                <Longitude>-6.0</Longitude>
                <Latitude>70.0</Latitude>
              </Translation>
            </Location>
</locations>    
"""
```

Something like this:

```
stop_points = data.select('location')
columns=['Id','One','Two','Three','Four']
rows = []

for s in stop_points:        
    row = []
    row.append(s['id'])
    row.extend(s.text.strip().split('\n'))
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

should output:

```
     Id     One     Two     Three   Four
0   00000   111111  222222  -5.0    50.0
1   00001   4444    5555    -6.0    70.0
```